# Google places autocomplete is not returning correct places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I followed the following tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

And, the resulting code I wrote has the following instantiation for the google places autocomplete (I'm using Node.js with browserify so it looks a little different):

```
enableAutoCompleteForElement: function(aDomElement) {
    var self = this;

    // The geocode type restricts the search to geographical location types.
    GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = ArbitratorConfig.google_api_key;
    GoogleMapsLoader.LIBRARIES = ['places'];
    GoogleMapsLoader.SENSOR = false;

    console.log("Google client id: " + ArbitratorConfig.google_client_id);

    GoogleMapsLoader.load(function(google) {
      self.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(aDomElement,
                                                              { types: ['geocode'] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(self.autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, this will fire.
        var place = self.autocomplete.getPlace();
      });
    });
  }
```

This works quite well, for most applications. However, I've noticed that it's not quite as accurate as the places autocomplete bundled with Google Calendar. For example, if I create an event in Google Calendar and do a search in the location input for 'Bloomington Ice Garden', it will (probably depending on your location to start with) return a result of 'Bloomington Ice Garden, West 98th Street, Minneapolis, MN, United States'. However, if I perform the same search with my client, it doesn't bring up this result. The closest I can get is 'Bloomington, MN, United States'.

I feel like I'm missing part of the library, or I'm incorrectly telling it to do something that it shouldn't be doing. I'd like to be able to retrieve any type of place that's registered with Google Places - not just cities, states, or countries (which appears to be what it's autocompleting currently).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `types: ['geocode']` option from your `Autocomplete`.  That's what's causing Google Places Autocomplete to exclude places like 'Bloomington Ice Garden', which is an establishment and not a geocode.